# Can residuals from linear regression be used to test for normality?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, residuals, normality-assumption, pspp

I want to perform an ANOVA test for which the normality of residuals must be tested. I am using a statistical software package called PSPP which does not have the option of performing normality tests like the Shapiro Wilks test of normality. In SPSS, I find that people generally perform a univariate analysis (linear) and save the residuals for performing a normality test or for examining the skewness and kurtosis values for determining whether the residuals are normally distributed.

Now, in PSPP, which I use, there is no option for saving the residuals while performing univariate, analysis. However, while performing a regression analysis in pspp, there is an option for saving the 
residuals. I am aware that the residuals from the univaraite analysis and the residuals from the regression analysis are not one and the same.

Can I still use the residuals from regression to test for normality and perform an ANOVA? Is there any other solution?

Comment: It sounds like you have software that doesn’t perform the test you want to perform, so it doesn’t matter what you save; you won’t be able to do the test. The general sentiment on Cross Validated, however, is that formal hypothesis testing of goodness-of-fit is not useful. You either have too few observations to reject the null or you have so many observations that you reject the null despite the difference not being of practical significance. Graphical examination of the residuals will be your friend.

Comment: Hopefully to clarify:  in some contexts "univariate" means there is a single dependent variable.  E.g., ANOVA instead of MANOVA.  Otherwise:  if you use the same model in each context -- same use of listwise deletion, same dependent, same predictors each treated the same way (e.g., with respect to squared terms, interactions, the number of levels or dummies for any categorical variables), then regression and a procedure such as SPSS's Unianova or PSPP's Univariate will in fact produce the same residuals.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that there is no save option in PSPP for saving the residuals of the univariate analysis. Is there a syntax command for saving the residuals that you know of? Thanks.

Comment: Can you save the fitted (predicted) values of the regression? Why you’re working in a language that doesn’t support a basic task you want to do is quite puzzling, though.

Comment: @Dave I can save the predicted values from linear regression. However not from univariate analysis (GLM).

Comment: Okay. I tested the normality of the dependent variable and turns out, it is not normally distributed. Can I then assume that the residuals will be non-normal too?